# Firebase/Angular: Messages not showing in HTML, but contain the message objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Good day SO,

I am trying to incorporate a basic firebase chat module into my system via angular js (I am honestly not proficient at all..)

I am facing a problem whereby my items are not showing in my HTML element although my firebase messages are being retrieved from my firebase database.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="chatApp">

...

<section id="content3" class="tab-content">
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
                Instant Chat Messenger – Crisis Management Office
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" ng-controller="ChatController">
            <p ng-repeat="m in messages">{{m.message}}- </p>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-11">  
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chatEntry" rows="14" placeholder="Type your message here" ng-model="messageText">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-1">   
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="sendBtn" ng-click="send()">Send</button>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is the angular.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('chatApp', ['firebase']);

app.controller('ChatController', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {

    var crisis = "Crisis1";

    //Query

    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child(crisis).child('CMO-PMO');

    $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);

    $scope.send = function() {
        $scope.messages.$add({
            sender: "PMO",
            message: $scope.messageText,
            date: Date.now()
        })
    }
})
```

And now, here is the funny thing.. My messages are being retrieved (I put a dash '-' behind {{ m.messages }} so that a dash will print for each message in my firebase database (To show that they are being retrieved), but my messages are not being shown.

Here is a screenshot of my firebase (Note: has 7 messages currently):

[image]

And here is a screenshot of my HTML page (It shows 7 dashes for 7 items in my firebase):

[image]

Although I have checked my scope in the javascript code, as well as the namings in my firebase database, my messages are still unable to show.. But I am able to send messages via my page to the firebase database. (The button and send functions are working!) The only problem now is showing the messages..

I am at a loss.. Please help me SO! I will promptly reply to any posts here :) Thank you so much!

Edit: If i use {{m|json}}:

[image]

Comment: Instead `{{m.message}}- ` try `{{m|json}}- `, what do u c?

Comment: Hi! I received an error: TemplateSyntaxError, Invalid filter: 'json', picture is in the question at the bottom, is it because i'm developing using Django and Python as well?

Comment: Just realised that javascript parsing is different when you have django/python in.. I still cannot find a way to render the messages into my HTML page..

Comment: fixed using the {% verbatim %} tag.. after 3 hours dang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the rendering problem using the `{%verbatim%}` tag.