# Django/AngularJS: How do I access my Python Context Items from my AngularJS Script

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, json, django

Good day SO! I am a beginner thats trying out a Django Project while using AngularJS for my frontend Firebase chat system. Here is a previous question that I asked regarding this project: [Firebase/Angular: Messages not showing in HTML, but contain the message objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756104/firebase-angular-messages-not-showing-in-html-but-contain-the-message-objects?noredirect=1#comment80457752_46756104)

I know that it is not wise to use json variables on your html directly while using django/python, but it just so happens that my firebase chat module is using angularJS (and I do not know how to code this chat function in django..), and my angularJS code requires access to my Django's context querysets from View.py.

Is there any way that I can either:

1. Push json items into my HTML/Template the same way I push context
   information into my HTML/Template from Views.py and use it in my
   AngularJS Script?
2. Access my Django/Python's data sets from Context from Views.py?

Here is my AngularJS code for firebase:

```
var app = angular.module('chatApp', ['firebase']);

app.controller('ChatController', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {

    //I want to populate the crisis and sender variables  with something from my context 
    //from Views.py.. Inside planList

    var crisis = "Crisis1"; 
    var sender = "Sender1";

    //Query

    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child(crisis).child('CMO-PMO');

    $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);

    $scope.send = function() {
        $scope.messages.$add({
            sender: sender,
            message: $scope.messageText,
            date: Date.now()
        })
    }
})
```

And here is my Views.py Code:

```
def home(request):
    template = loader.get_template('app/home.html')
    planList = Plan.objects.filter(plan_crisisID__crisis_status='Ongoing')

    context = {        
        'planList': planList
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Both variables needed in my AngularJS code (crisis and sender) are from the planList context.

Is there any way for me to achieve this? Please give me some assistance.. Thank you so much and I greatly appreciate it :) I will gladly provide any additional information if needed, and will reply promptly too!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use an API for it. You can create an API using [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) very easily. For example:

```
# Serializer
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = Plan
        fields = ('model_fields',)

# Views:
from rest_framework import generics


Class SomeView(generics.ListView):
      queryset = Plan.objects.all()
      serializer_class = SomeSerializer


# urls

url(r'^plans$', SomeView.as_view()),
```

In Angular JS, if you use [angular-resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), you can simply get the data by:

```
res = $resource('/plans')
res.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)},  // You get your data in here
    function(error) {
    console.log(error)}
)
```